# a way to check for the existence of a function in the document and window object in Script#

Tags: script#

I am trying to convert statements that check the existence of functions in document and window objects but I don't find any elegant form in ScriptSharp:

```
// Javascript expected result

if (document.getElementById)



// Current ScriptSharp

if (!Script.IsNullOrUndefined(Script.Literal("document.getElementById"))
```

Is there a better way that I didn't think of?

If I do something like:

```
if (Dictionary.GetDictionary(Document).ContainsKey("getElementById"))
```

I get an error because Document is a type and not an object.. is there a way to get the javascript document object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Type.HasField.

```
if (Type.HasField(typeof(Document), "getElementById")) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify it to use `typeof` operator

```
if (Dictionary.GetDictionary(typeof(Document)).ContainsKey("getElementById"))
```